# Maximize the number of satisfied disjunctions

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming, satisfiability

I have ~4000 variables that are used in ~5000 logical formulas, where each formula consists only of conjunctions of the (non-negated) variables. I want to find the maximum number of satisfied formulas, given the number of variables that I can set to 1.

Does this problem have a name? Is it equivalent to the MAX-SAT problem? Which algorithm would be applicable to solve it exactly or using heuristics?

Answer (score 3):

You are addressing a problem of the same type. if you use De Morgan law your problem will become [MIN-SAT](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/97e0/d770ffca132573b0aac289760814f7e276c5.pdf) which is  NP-HARD

checkout [THE MINIMUM SATISFIABILITY PROBLEM](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/97e0/d770ffca132573b0aac289760814f7e276c5.pdf)

Comment: But how can I restrict the number of variables that can be set to 1?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are asking for, but if you mean:
Given a set of formlas on the set of variables V (where you have |V| = n variables). and you want to select k variables and check how many formulas you can satisfy based on those k variables.
Then you can pick the k variables, and set the rest to 0 so only the k variables can force a formula to be satisfied :)